# Is a String variable considered an object

Tags: java, string

Are `String` variables considered objects? Does the following line create an answer object? Will the variable `answer`be an object or will it be a primitive type?

```
String answer = readLine("what is your answer? :")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java primitive declarations are all lowercase eg `double d1=0.55;` ,keyword *double* is all lowercase while for objects they have first letter caps e.g String,Double,List etc . so answer is an object in this case. download the Java API docs they come in handy

Comment: This is the best answer here, and really the only correct one, because it's (currently) the only one that doesn't assert that `String` is an object.  Sure, in Java, classes can be viewed as objects of the `Class` class, but that's beside the point.  Every other answer has confused the concept of "class" with the concept of "object"; and people who don't understand the distinction shouldn't be posting answers to this type of question.

Comment: I would just like to add a trivial detail to avoid any confusion, The fact use of lowercase letters has nothing to do with the something being a primitive. In Java their are 8 primitive types (byte, short, int, long, float, double, char & boolean). Everything else is an Object.

Comment: @DavidWallace I don't think the question is asking if `String` itself is an object - you are correct, `String` is a class. I think the question was is the `answer` an object or a primitive. An instance of a string is an object, whereas `String` is a class. while that's what I meant with my original answer, I have updated it to be clearer.

Comment: @DavidWallace A `String` *is* an object, just as every (non-primitive) thing in Java is an object, because everything ultimately inherits from object.

Comment: Yes, @Dgrin91, a String is an object.  String instances are objects.  "String" is a class.

Comment: Clearly @R.daneel.olivaw is confused somewhere...idk what SDK u use but NEVER in my life have I been able to create a class whose name starts with a lowercase character so it is absolutely safe and correct to assume that if your declaration starts with an upper case that is an object not a primitive! or are thereany primitives out there that start with an uppercase character? school me,mayble Eclipse and the APIs have lied to me

Comment: Hello @Manny264, I think Java class names are nothing but Java identifiers, an identifier in Java can start with any alphabet or any currency symbol. Having an uppercase letter in the beginning of a Java class name is a very helpful standard that everyone follows. Please refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html at section 3.8

Comment: i'll follow that standard you can follow whichever

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Strings are Java object. If you check documentation: [Java - String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), you'll find that it extends java.lang.Object:

```
public final class String
extends Object
implements Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
```

Answer (score 4):

`String` *instances* are objects, not primitive types. `String` is a class.

Comment: And as a result (of `String` being an object), `==` doesn't do what new programmers expect it to do when comparing `String`s, and as a result... lots of SO posts.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I know.  That's what I was saying.

Comment: @nhgrif :P My bad, mis-read...hmmm, I think it's caffine time

Answer (score 3):

Instances of Class `String` are Objects.

Looking at it's javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html, it is confirmed.

```
java.lang.Object
extended by java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, it is by convention that Object types begin with a Capital letter and primitive types begin with a lowercase letter.

That being said, String is an Object, not a primitive.

Comment: Very interesting point. Never considered that objects begin with capitals and primitive types being with lowercase letters.

Comment: ... by which you mean that the names of Object TYPES (such as classes and interfaces) begin with capital letters, and the names of primitive TYPES begin with lower case letters.  In the OP's example, "answer" is the name that one object goes by, and it begins with a lower case A.  "String" is a CLASS.

Comment: You've really strived to make your point David Wallace but u are so right,thats one silly mistake i hope i dont make in my job interview.

Answer (score 1):

String is an object, it isn't a primitive type at all.